# how to query three different databases and merge all result in a flat text file by SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I need to consume  three different databases(from three different servers) and merge all three result-set and insert that merged result in a flat file.

I created three Sql queries
query1 for serverA.TableA
query2 for serverB.TableB
query3 for serverC.TableC

all three result-set has common columns to merge them with each other (to one merged result-set) with join statement.

How can i execute those queries (against the related sql servers) and join result-sets to create a text file by a SSIS package.

Environment is MS Sql Server 2008 R2 & SSIS

Comment: I'd say Jayvee's is the better answer, and here is a tutorial for doing what he says:  http://www.ssistutorial.com/create_join_between_datasets_in_ssis.php  (The tutorial adds sorting, but I'm sure you can skip that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data flow should look like this:[image]

each ole db source will contain the sqls and connection managers pointing to the required servers, make sure you use order by in the sqls, so you don't need to sort the output later for the merge joins.

Comment: PS: you also need to set the isSort property to True in all three sources. To do this, you may need to right click each one and select 'show advance editor' then Input and Output Properties tab, then click on Source output and set the property to true. You will also need to click on the output column(s) that the sql is ordered by  and set the sortkeyposition property.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. The hard part was setting up the column order in flat file. I removed all columns from advance tab of file connection manager and repopulated them.

Comment: i also created another question as a continuation of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084684/how-to-create-different-flat-files-depends-on-the-result-set-in-ssis-package

Answer (score 0):

```
First create a Data flow task
```

Inside the dataflow task,  Create 3 OLEDB connections and make use those connection in OLE   DB source components.Now all the 3 sources are ready for querying.

```
Use Union all components and union all the data 

Make a text file connection for the flat file target and map the columns
```

Validate and press F5